# Can manually triggered cron jobs respect the concurrencyPolicy?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob, kubernetes-jobs

So I've a cron job like this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: my-cron-job
spec:
  schedule: "0 0 31 2 *"
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  concurrencyPolicy: "Forbid"
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 30
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      backoffLimit: 0
      activeDeadlineSeconds: 120
...
```

Then i trigger the job manually like so:

```
kubectl create job my-job --namespace precompile --from=cronjob/my-cron-job
```

But it seams like I can trigger the job as often as I want and the `concurrencyPolicy: "Forbid"` is ignored.

Is there a way so that manually triggered jobs will respect this or do I have to check this manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Note that concurrency policy only applies to the jobs created by the same cron job.

The `concurrencyPolicy` field only applies to jobs created by the same cron job, as stated in the documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#concurrency-policy

When executing `$ kubectl create job my-job --namespace precompile --from=cronjob/my-cron-job` you are essentially creating a one-time job on its own that uses the `spec.jobTemplate` field as a reference to create it. Since `concurrencyPolicy` is a cronjob field, it is not even being evaluated.

**TL;DR**

This actually is the expected behavior. Manually created jobs are not effected by `concurrencyPolicy`. There is no flag you could pass to change this behavior.